# Need the contents under "with_items" to be in separate file and include them in main playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

I need the contents under "with_items:" to be in a separate file, include/ call them in main playbook and how to make the syntax for include the contents in overall playbook.

with_items contents

```
 with_items:
        - { vm_id: 101, vm_name: vm1, vm_cores: 2, vm_sockets: 1, vm_memory: 2048, vm_storage: 20G }
        - { vm_id: 102, vm_name: vm2, vm_cores: 2, vm_sockets: 1, vm_memory: 2048, vm_storage: 20G }
```

I tried creating a new file as "list.yaml"

```
vars:
  list: vars/list.yaml
```

included the list.yaml like below

```
 with_items: "{{ list }}"
```

and used the content like example

```
cpu: "{{ item.vm_cores }}"
```

---

is am i missing something or any other way around for this

Comment: please read the text of the [tag:linux] tag you nave included on your question. Please delete here and repost to [unix.se]. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat list.yaml
- {vm_id: 101, vm_name: vm1, vm_cores: 2, vm_sockets: 1, vm_memory: 2048, vm_storage: 20G}
- {vm_id: 102, vm_name: vm2, vm_cores: 2, vm_sockets: 1, vm_memory: 2048, vm_storage: 20G}
```

Use the *file* [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "cpu: {{ item.vm_cores }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'list.yaml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'cpu: 2'
  msg: 'cpu: 2'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "cpu: {{ item.vm_cores }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'list.yaml')|from_yaml }}"
```